# Optimised way to transfer big integer arrays from javascript to flask and viceversa

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, flask

I want to pass a dictionary of big uint8 1-dimensional arrays (2 arrays, ~ 1'000'000 elements per array) from javascript to flask and viceversa. I know how to do the transferring via fetch and json stringify (see code below) but I somehow suppose there might be a better solution which requires less bandwidth and is more performant. I just need to transfer unsigned integers and not any strings. I also use [flask-compress](https://github.com/colour-science/flask-compress) to reduce the amount of data to be transmitted.

My code so far:

**backend.py with flask**

```
import json
import flask
import numpy as np
from flask_compress import Compress

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
Compress(app)

@app.route('/save_mask', methods=['POST'])
def save_mask():
    data = json.loads(flask.request.data)
    mask = np.array(data['mask'])
    ...
```

**frontend.html with javascript**

```
fetch("/save_mask", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'mask': mask,
            'pixels': pixels
        })
    })
```

What is the best way to transfer *bare* uint8 arrays without using json?

Answer (score 1):

Since that is uint8 array, you can convert it to a "bytes string" using for loop and https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr and on the JS side, you can restore it from the "bytes string" using for and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charcodeat.asp as well.

Also, of course, you can compress that that string using gzip or etc, but not sure about your JS libraries available and so on.

### Server-side example for python to send ints array as a base64 encoded string

```
>>> import base64, json, array
>>> source = [123, 23, 11, 31, 51, 123, 112, 112, 221, 51, 12, 41, 2]
>>> json.dumps({'values': source})
'{"values": [123, 23, 11, 31, 51, 123, 112, 112, 221, 51, 12, 41, 2]}'
>>> len(json.dumps({'values': source}))
68
>>> json.dumps({'values': base64.encodestring(array.array('B', source).tostring()).decode('ascii')})
'{"values": "excLHzN7cHDdMwwpAg==\\n"}'
>>> len(json.dumps({'values': base64.encodestring(array.array('B', source).tostring()).decode('ascii')}))
36
```

In the example, as you see we "packed our ints array to a base64 encoded bytes string" `excLHzN7cHDdMwwpAg==\\n` which is shorter obviously rather than JSON representation for the same ints list `[123, 23, 11, 31, 51, 123, 112, 112, 221, 51, 12, 41, 2]`

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Why is it better to convert my integers to a byte string before transferring them?

Comment: because byte string will use 1 byte per 1 uint8 integer instead of 1-3 (plus a comma per int for a delimiter)

Comment: Is there no option to just pass the pure byte from the integer? What I basically want is to circumvent json.stringify.

Comment: no, because JSON is a **STRING** representation of an object, it doesn't work with any binary data. You should convert your ints array to some sort of string (and do it back on the client-side). Let me add an example of python server-side conversion